# Mojolicious and packaged routes?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

Mojolicious has a routes object named [Mojolicious::Routes](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Routes). I would like to create one of these outside of my app, independent of it so I could export these routes and import them into my app..

```
use Mojolicious::Routes;

sub _gen_route {
  my $r = Mojolicious::Routes->new;
  $r->get('/foo')->to(sub{ print "hello, foo" });
  $r;
}
```

Then in a Mojo application

```
sub startup {
  my $self = shift;
  my $r = shift;

  $r->get('/bar')->to(sub{ print "hello, bar" });

  $r->import_router(_gen_route())
}
```

Is there anyway to compose routers? Ie., package up a route and import it into Apps router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to create a [`Mojolicious::Plugin`](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Plugins). The plugin's **register** method is called on startup and has access to the app and through it to its routes.

So, your route-adding module would look like this:

```
package MyRouteGen;
use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious::Plugin';

sub register {
  my ($self, $app, $conf) = @_;
  $name = ($conf && defined $conf->{'name'}) ? $conf->{'name'} : 'foo'; 
  return $app->routes->get('/foo')
                     ->to(sub{ 
                            shift->render(text => "hello, $name")
                        });
 }
```

Then in a Mojo application:

```
sub startup {
 my $app = shift;
 $app->plugin('MyRouteGen', { name => 'baz' });
 $app->get('/bar')->to(sub{ print "hello, bar" });
 ...
}
```